# PHP: Error: SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: parameter was not defined

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

Estoy haciendo un método de Login pero no puedo solucionar este error, agradecería mucho su ayuda

```
<?php
  try {
    $base = new PDO("mysql:host = localhost; dbname = estimasoft", "root", "");
    $base->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM usuario WHERE nombre = :nombre AND contraseña = :contraseña";
    $resultado = $base->prepare($sql);
    $nombre = htmlentities(addslashes($_POST["nombre"]));
    //echo $nombre;
    $contraseña = htmlentities(addslashes($_POST["contraseña"]));
    $resultado->bindValue(':nombre', $nombre);
    $resultado->bindValue(':contraseña', $contraseña);
    $resultado->execute();
    $numeroRegistro = $resultado->rowCount();
    if($numeroRegistro == 1){
        echo "adelante";
    }else{
      header("location: ../index1.php");
    }
} catch (Exception $e) {
    die("Error: ".$e->getMessage());
}
?>
```

y el formulario es este :

```
<form class="container col-lg-4 col-lg-offset-4" action="sistema/comprueba_login.php" method="post">
    <div class="form-group">
         <label for="user">Usuario:</label>
         <input class="form-control" type="text" name="nombre" value="" id="user" placeholder="Usuario">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
         <label for="password">Contraseña:</label>
         <input class="form-control" type="password" name="contraseña" value="" id="password" placeholder="Contraseña">
   </div>
   <div class="row">
        <input class="btn btn-default col-lg-4 col-lg-offset-4" type="submit" name="name" value="Ingresar">
   </div>
</form>
```

Comment: Puede ser por el nombre de la columna contraseña, es posible que no este reconociendo la letra ñ en ':contraseña'.

Comment: Lo probare gracias :D

Comment: Pruebalo y luego dices como te fue.

Comment: ahora me bota este error :( -> Error: SQLSTATE[3D000]: Invalid catalog name: 1046 No database selected

Comment: Eso se debe al nombre de la base de datos, revisa si esta bien escrito el nombre de la base de datos en tu cadena de conexion PDO

Comment: @JuanPinzón gracias amigo, me haz sido de mucha ayuda, ya arregle el problema, de verdad te agradezco! :D

Comment: De nada, ya agregué una respuesta a tu pregunta, si te sirvió marcala como solución a la misma, así otros usuarios pueden encontrarla útil.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

En base a los comentarios el error

> SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: parameter was not defined

Puede ser por el nombre de la columna contraseña, es posible que no este reconociendo la letra ñ en ':contraseña'.

y el error

> SQLSTATE[3D000]: Invalid catalog name: 1046 No database selected

se debe al nombre de la base de datos, revisa si esta bien escrito el nombre de la base de datos en tu cadena de conexión PDO