# Fatal error: Uncaught PDOException: SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: parameter was not defined (Creando formulario de ingreso)

Tags: php, mysql

Estoy haciendo un formulario para ingresar los datos de un usuario, después de ingresarlos y darle enviar me sale el siguiente error:

> Fatal error: Uncaught PDOException: SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: parameter was not defined.justamente en la linea 28: if($stmt->execute()){

Aquí el código:

```
$tabla = "usuarios";
$datos = array("nombre" => $_POST["nuevoNombre"], "usuario" => $_POST["nuevoUsuario"], "contraseña" => $_POST["nuevoContraseña"], "perfil" => $_POST["nuevoPerfil"]);

$respuesta = ModeloUsuarios::MdlIngresarUsuarios($tabla, $datos);

static public function MdlIngresarUsuarios($tabla, $datos){
    $stmt = Conexion::conectar()->prepare("INSERT INTO $tabla(nombre, usuario, contraseña, perfil) VALUES (:nombre, :usuario, :contraseña, :perfil)");  

    $stmt -> bindParam(":nombre", $datos["nombre"], PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $stmt -> bindParam(":usuario", $datos["usuario"], PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $stmt -> bindParam(":contraseña", $datos["contraseña"], PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $stmt -> bindParam(":perfil", $datos["perfil"], PDO::PARAM_STR);

    if($stmt->execute()){
        return "ok";
    }else{
        return "error";
    }
    $stmt -> close();
    $stmt = null;
}
```

Comment: Quizá esto te ayude a solucionar tu problema [php-error-sqlstatehy093-invalid-parameter-number-parameter-was-not-defined](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/10073/php-error-sqlstatehy093-invalid-parameter-number-parameter-was-not-defined)

Comment: Y, **¿cuál es la línea 28?** El código parece correcto, lo que te podría estar fastidiando aquí sería la `ñ`, la cual podría dar problemas si no hilas fino con la codificación, por eso **se recomienda siempre evitar nombres de tablas, columnas y variables de PHP con `ñ` o acentos**, incluso es mejor que programes con una convención de nombre en inglés, porque nunca tendrás problemas de codificación y porque permite crear variables más claras y breves.